# Discard pile and melding

Tags: canasta

My opponent picks up the discard pile but then cannot meld. What to do?

Comment: This is not at all a duplicate of the linked question…

Comment: @GendoIkari I've reopened it, I agree it wasn't a dupe of the linked ones.

Comment: @CesarM I found the second link after seeing the other close votes; I do believe it’s a duplicate of that one and thus should be close… just not closed as the original duplicate.

Comment: @GendoIkari I understand it as a different - that one deals with if you show an invalid meld. This is asking what to do if you pick a card but then figure out that you can't meld (before showing). Might make a difference, might not, but I see them as different scenarios. Happy to re-close if you think so even after this

Comment: Ah good point, this question doesn’t clarify that the player has exposed their hand; which the other question deals with.